# vb.net application login using mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

im trying to let users login to an application i created in vb.net using the user table of the application's database in mysql

i heard that The usual way to do this is to have just one MySQL user called "[my_app_name]" with the relevant permissions. Then my application uses it's own user table to control access to the application, and the one MySQL user to access the database. but i dont know how to do it, can someone please help me with it. im new to all this.

thanks

Comment: you don't know how to do what? Create an app or setup the database call or create a mysql user or create a mysql database?  Be a little more specific on what you've tried and what you need help with.

Comment: The problem is i have a table called user which contains the usernames and passwords of all my users but they cant login till i go into the mysql workbench server administration and give them direct access to the database but someone told me that instead of doing that, the usual way to do this is to have just one MySQL user called "[my_app_name]" with the relevant permissions. Then my app uses it's own user table to control access to the app, and the one MySQL user to access the database. 
that is what i need help with, letting the app use its own user table without giving direct access.

Answer (score 1):

If you're making a login form that will check for authetication with users and their passwords on a MySQL database just follow this code I wrote for my own login form.

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click

    Dim conn As MySqlConnection

        'Connect to the database using these credentials
        conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "your server goes here; user id=userid goes here; password=self explanatory; database=the database where the credential information is located"

        'Try and connect (conn.open)
        Try
            conn.Open()

        Catch myerror As MySqlException 'If it fails do this... (i.e. no internet connection, etc.)
        MsgBox("Error connecting to database. Check your internet connection.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try


        'MySQL query (where to call for information)
        Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter

        'Tell where to find the file with the emails/passes stored
    Dim sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM your database with info WHERE Email = '" & txtEmail.Text & "' AND Password = '" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
        myCommand.Connection = conn
        myCommand.CommandText = sqlquery

        'Start query
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
        Dim myData As MySqlDataReader
        myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader

        'See if the user exists
        If myData.HasRows = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Invalid email address or password.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

        'Insert your settings change here. (i.e. My.Settings.LoggedIn = False)

        Else
        MsgBox("Logged in as " & txtEmail.Text & ".", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

        'Another settings change: My.Settings.LoggedIn = True

            Me.Close() 'close the login form

    End If
```

Be sure to change the control names and also add a setting.

Answer (score 0):

Open up MySQL Workbench and towards the bottom right of the first screen, under the "Server Administration" column,  you'll see "Manage Security". Click on that. In the menu to the left you will see "Users and Privileges". Click on that. You'll see a button that says "Add Account" which, when clicked, will allow you to create a new user. In the Schema Privileges tab you can modify the user's permissions.

The user you created here can be used in your connection string. Here is an example MySQL connection string from one of my applications. The username in the connection string below, repair, was created with "Login Name:" as "repair" and "Limit Connectivity to Hosts Matching:" as "%".

"Server=10.0.0.113;uid=repair;pwd='password&92';database=repair"

I hope this helps. Have a great day.